# Can I mount multiple partitions of a single GCE disk to a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like use a single **google compute engine** *disk* and mount it to multiple places a *Kubernetes* **Google Container Engine**.

I'm wondering if using `persistentVolumeClaim` would work, but what I did expect to work is being able to mount two partitions of the same disk:

```
  ...
  volumes:
    - name: database
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: dist-1
        fsType: ext4
        partition: 1
        readOnly: true
    - name: media
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: disk-1
        fsType: ext4
        partition: 2
        readOnly: true
```

Mounting either of them separately works, but trying to mount both gives an error:

```
FailedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "frontend-ni7uf_foo": Could not attach GCE PD "disk-1". Timeout waiting for mount paths to be created.
```

Technically I can manually mount both partitions on a single instance.

I'm wondering if it's a bug and if there is another solution for that (outside of having multiple disks)?

Comment: It looks like PV/PVC doesn't solve this issue as a PVC of 1Gi when there is a single PV disk of 10Gi, will result in 10Gi claimed.

Comment: Is that a typo in `pdName: dist-1`?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it Google Container Engine requires `readOnly` on both:

```
containers:
  - volumeMounts:
      - readOnly: true
volumes:
  - gcePersistentDisk:
      readOnly: true
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the question Wernight.

In order for (different partitions of) the same volume to be mounted in multiple places it must be read-only at the moment.

I opened https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20835 to track if this is the behavior we want moving forward or not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting the question differently than the other answers.  Why should it not be possible to mount different partitions of a single PD in a single pod, all read-write.  The PD is still attached to one node and used by one pod.

The only answer is that we didn't think of that as a use case.  Most people do not sub-partition block devices this way, in our experience, except when booting an OS.

If this is an important use-case to you, I encourage you to file a github issue on it.  I don't immediately know how to evolve to solve it, but I don't think it is an errant request.

Comment: I think Saad Ali did that. It's important mostly to avoid mounting to one place and doing `ln -s` hacks to have folders where my application expects it. Overall I've a decent amount of websites and they were not built with Kubernetes in mind. One example is Django which by default suggests to put uploaded media usually next to static files and databases is different folders but the result is that it requires 2 folders to mount. I change directory structure for those; it's just an example.

Comment: Another use case is [GitLab](http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/) which requires 3 mount points. Having those 3 on a single disk makes more sense to me as those should be kept in sync.

Comment: Having multiple partitions on one disk means that one disk shares things like IOPS.  I would not suggest doing it unless you really need it, if for no other reason than it doesn't work right in kubernetes.  That said, I wouldn't be against fixing it.

Comment: I'm fine sharing IOPS. Actually all I'd like is multiple mount point so subfolders of a volume could be mounted to different locations. Why? It's not about cost of a 10GB disk as much as it is to keep data together if they should be, so that for example a snapshot would snapshot all data required for a service.

Comment: Please open a github issue if there isn't one.

Comment: I have a similar use case for an import job where I'd like one container to index a file in elasticsearch, and simultaneously have another container upload the file to google storage with `gsutil cp`.  The problem is that the Python script tends to be pretty resource hungry, and the indexing job sometimes crashes.  So it would be nice to have resource isolation.  For this use case only one needs to write (to download the file), the other just needs read access.  I can probably solve it with a Pod though.