# purpose of kubernetes accessModes in pv | pvc

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes you can set volumes permissions at pod ,pv or pvc levels.
You can define pv | pvc as read only but still can write to the mount point if **readOnly** attribute is set to **false** which is pretty confusing.
I have read a lot of articles about this but still can't fully understand the purpose.

What I inderstand:

- Permissions at pv level are for requesting available ressouces from the host file system with at least the same permissions defined in pv.
- Permissions at pvc level are for requesting pv with at least the same permissions defined in pvc.
- Permissions at pod level are for setting permissions to the mount point.

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: What do you mean by `volumes permissions at pv or pvc levels` ?
Do you mean `accessModes`  ?

Comment: @matt_j y yes accesModes

Answer (score 1):

The `PV`'s (and `PVC`'s) access modes are used only for binding `PVC` (`PV`).

As you can see in this [github discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60903#issuecomment-377086770):

> AccessModes as defined today, only describe node attach (not pod mount) semantics, and doesn't enforce anything.

Additionally you can find useful information in the [PV AccessModes documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/dedicated/4/storage/understanding-persistent-storage.html#pv-access-modes_understanding-persistent-storage):

> A volume’s AccessModes are descriptors of the volume’s capabilities. They are not enforced constraints. The storage provider is responsible for runtime errors resulting from invalid use of the resource.
> For example, NFS offers ReadWriteOnce access mode. You must mark the claims as read-only if you want to use the volume’s ROX capability.

To enforce `readOnly` mode you can use:

`Pod.spec.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.readOnly` - controls if volume is in readonly mode.

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208276/14801225) may be of great help to you.